# Нужно сделать фильтрацию по id поста из данных json

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

есть два json файла. В одном хранятся комментария, в другом посты. Нужно сделать фильтрацию по postId  из json файла комменатриев.
json файл постов выглядит примерно так:
[
{"id": 1,
"name":"Artyr",
"text":"good morning"
},
{"id":2,
"username":"Sanya",
"text":"good evening"
}]
json файл комментариев выглядит так:
[{"postId":1,
"id":1,
"author":"Alex",
"text":"добрый вечер я диспетчер"},
{"postId":2,
"id":2,
"author":"Alex",
"text":"random text"}
]
нужно, чтобы при фильтрации выходили комментария к конкретным постам.
Пример: postId === id(поста)

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Изменил текст .

Answer (score 0):

```js
const comments = [{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Artyr",
  "text": "good morning"
}, {
  "id": 2,
  "username": "Sanya",
  "text": "good evening"
}]

const posts = [{
  "postId": 1,
  "id": 1,
  "author": "Alex",
  "text": "добрый вечер я диспетчер"
}, {
  "postId": 2,
  "id": 2,
  "author": "Alex",
  "text": "random text"
}]

const [selectedCommentId, setSelectedCommentId] = useState();

const selectedPostText = posts.find(post => post.postId === selectedCommentId)?.text;
```